# How to get the universalPrincipalName Object from smartcard?

Tags: c, smartcard, pkcs#11

I'm using the pkcs11 lib to do it, but I can't find a attribute corresponding to the universalPrincipalName I want to store in my program.

Here is the result from dumpasn1 :

```
SEQUENCE {
   OBJECT IDENTIFIER subjectAltName (52 565 529 177) 
   OCTET STRING, encapsulates {
     SEQUENCE {
        [0] {
          OBJECT IDENTIFIER
            universalPrincipalName (1 783 756 578 457 155 473 200 654 565)
          [0] {
            UTF8String 'thefoo.bar@foo.com'
            }
          }
```

How can I get 'thefoo.bar@foo.com' to store that field in a variable.

I think I need to use the CK_ATTRIBUTEs but none seems to correspond to the universalPrincipalName (ie. 'thefoo.bar@foo.com')

```
CK_ATTRIBUTE getattribute[] = {
            {CKA_WHICH_ONE_TO_USE, NULL_PTR, 0}
    };

C_GetAttributeValue(hSession, privKeyObject, getattribute, size);
```

Is C_GetAttributeValue the right function to get this info or is there maybe another way to get the universalPrincipalName ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard PKCS#11 attribute defined for UPN. You need to read whole certificate (CKA_VALUE attribute of certificate object) and parse it yourself.

Comment: I don't know how to parse the certificate. How can I tell to just read the UPN from the corresponding object identifier ? Is there function to get object identifier's name ?

Comment: With     CK_ATTRIBUTE data[2] = {
     {CKA_LABEL, NULL_PTR, 0},
     {CKA_VALUE, NULL_PTR, 0},
    };  I get this from C_GetAttributeValue : data[1].pValue=0��0�Ġ8��[�j�0 . So I can't parse it to retrieve UPN. Do I need to decode the result of pValue ?